# How to navigate to other component using functional component

Tags: react-native, react-router

I'm using `useHistory` for navigate one screen to other .. but here i;m getting issue called `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'history.push')` i dont know what is wrong here..please hlep me thanks in advance

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
 const history = useHistory();

function intiateVideoCall ()  {
 history.push('/ChatFunction');
}

const ChatFunction = ({ navigation }) => {
 <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
   <GiftedChat
    messages={messages}
   onSend={messages => handleSendMessage(messages)}
   />
</View>   
}

<TouchableOpacity
    style = {styles.submitButton}
    onPress = {intiateVideoCall}>
  <Text style = {styles.submitButtonText}> Connect </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't use react-router-dom on react-native. You can use react-navigation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/ or react-router-native https://reactrouter.com/native/guides/quick-start